# Different homepage for external users

Tags: redirect

My sharepoint farm is accessed both externally and internally and I was wondering what the best way of redirecting the **same URL** to 2 different pages?

When people go to our sharepoint URL internally, I'd like to show the company news frontpage at /Frontpage.aspx

When people go to our sharepoint URL externally, I'd like to show an external usage guide at /Tutorial.aspx

I was thinking a conditional host header to maybe redirect /Frontpage.aspx -> /Tutorial.aspx if IP address is external???

I'm using Sharepoint 2010 Standard and the URL is https.

Thanks all!

Comment: Are you using FBA for internal/external access OR what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way is to write a HttpModule and redirect accordingly.
OR
Use the URL Rewrite feature in IIS. (I believe it's an IIS 7 extension)

http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite